# Initial Full Backup Failing Immediately

Tags: sql-server, backup, sql-server-2014

This server was recently installed and configured.  I was in the process of creating some maintenance plans to backup the logs and DBs on a daily basis.  Regardless of my method to perform a full backup, it would fail immediately citing the generic error message

```
Error: 3041, Severity: 16, State: 1.
```

This is what I found in the SQL Error Logs:
[image]

[image]

I've never seen this before and wasn't able to find much during research.  I've verified that the associated service account has permissions to the backup folders and there is more than enough space.

Other details

- SQL 12.0.4213.0
- Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard
- VMware virtual machine

Comment: Are you able to successfully use `BACKUP DATABASE ... TO DISK = 'path to some file.bak';` to do the backup?

Comment: The associated graphics are the log result from using the GUI and TSQL.  The short answer is no.

Comment: Does `DBCC CHECKDB` show anything bad for the database in question?  Are you able to backup `master`?

Comment: 3041 is a generic message. Refer to [this KB for troubleshooting](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2646329)

Comment: @SeanPerkins You state `Regardless of my method to perform a full backup`, but I don't think you've shown any examples other than what you get when you run through `Maintenance Plan`. Please do as Max suggested with that METHOD (and TSQL example) and post your results to ensure it's not some `Maintenance Plan` related issue only. Also, refer to the article per Kin and post the additional logs referred to in that article and post yo your answer.`The detailed error messages are written only to the SQL Server error log and to the client application. ` Yours seem different from the MS KB examples.

Comment: @SeanPerkins Also, if you cannot find any other more definitive logs, you may need to enable verbose logging on the maint. plan somehow and then  check that log afterwards. If job history logs nor any sql error logs nor any perhaps maint. plan logs give more detail, you may need to enable verbose logs. Otherwise, running as Max mentioned from a query in SSMS may give the more conclusive error without needing to setup explicit verbose log for the method you are using. I just wanted to add that in case you are stating you cannot find anything further than the stack trace type logs you provided.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to update this post with what ended up working for me.  I don't know why, but running SSMS as Administrator allowed the backup to complete as you'd expect.